# Remap cancel (B) key in Starcraft 2?

Tags: starcraft-2

I've switched over to the grid keyboard layout. Works awesome. The one thing that sticks out is that if I need to cancel a unit movement, I can hit escape. However when using unit powers like shield, charge, whatever, I have to this the 'B' key to cancel it. That is so annoying because the B key is completely outside where my left hand is with the grid layout.

Is there anyway to change the 'B' cancel key to escape also?

Comment: I just hit it with my thumb.  But no, I don't think there's a way to remap keys.

Comment: @BlueRaja-DannyPflughoeft Yes, i do aswell. B is still within thumb distance of my hand.

Comment: [Just add spacebar as an alternative key to the B on the grid or something similar centering on the last ping is useless anyway](http://i272.photobucket.com/albums/jj186/EmilHansen/SC2kaymapping.jpg)

Comment: Cresh you should move your comment to be an answer I can accept. Thanks for the tip

Answer (score 2):

I like Cresh's suggestion to add another key as an alternate key.

---

In my case, I also wanted <kbd>ESC</kbd> to be Cancel and to use <kbd>B</kbd> for other things depending on the unit. So I chose to manually create a custom key mapping just like Grid, but with some slight modifications.

If <kbd>B</kbd> is your only complaint, then I don't recommend this because you have to populate almost every command (took about 2 hours with testing).

But if you're looking to have a very flexible and optimal key map, then my opinion is that it was well worth the time. And it's saved on your account, so you're custom key map is accessible on any computer.